# Highcharts with JQuery mobile Black display

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, highcharts

i am using the Highcharts library in my jquery mobile app.
The chart shows correctly and fully in colors but when this app runs in emmulator and also test in  `BlueStacks` but in both the chart (pi chart) is black in color.

Here is my app [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BluAngel/vk8bS/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many times are you calling this:

```
    Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
        return {
            radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
            stops: [
                [0, color],
                [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
            ]
        };
    });
```

Remove that lines and should work properly.